# Batch script to show in txt file latest file available in a directory, by date

Tags: file, date, batch-file

I have this simple batch script:

```
@echo off
dir /o-d "K:\DIR\DIR\*.exe" > "D:\Logs\Files.txt"
```

which displays all the files in a txt, by date.

My question is: how can I get this to show me only the last file by date and not all files in that specific directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

#### Retrieving the last line

If you're only interested in the *last* file, you can do this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /o-d "K:\DIR\DIR*.exe" ^| findstr /C:"/"') do set last=%%a
echo %last%
```

This displays only the last filename from the output of the `dir` command. If you want to redirect it to a file, replace `echo %last%` with:

```
echo %last% > "D:\Logs\Files.txt"
```

#### Retrieving the first line

If you're interested in the *first* file, you need to slightly alter the code to this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /o-d "K:\DIR\DIR*.exe" ^| findstr /C:"/"') do set first=%%a && goto Done
:Done
echo %first%
```

Again, if you're interested in redirecting it to a file, replace `echo %first%` with:

```
echo %first% > "D:\Logs\Files.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal 
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d') do (
  set file=%%~nxF %%~tF
  goto display
)
:display
echo %file%
```

Notes:

- To understand `for` and  'decrypt' `%%~nxF %%~tF`, read `for` help (`help for` from command line)
- `goto` is there just to break the loop after first (latest) file/dir.
- To redirect to file, either redirect the batch itself (`batch.bat >myFile`) or last echo (`echo %file% > myFile`)
- Dir matches subdirectories as well as files by default. Use
  `dir /a-d` to match files only.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible using shell/batch commands.

you may write another program to pick first line of Files.txt file

Answer (score 0):

to get only the file name of the latest file

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /b /o-d "K:\DIR\DIR\*.exe"') do (
    echo %%x
    exit /b 0
)
```